# Extract values from filename and add it into a text file

Tags: bash, sed, awk, find, filenames

I have a gridded model data (separated by different depth) saved in text files. The structure is like this:

**Format** of every column in a row in the text file:

```
x_coordinate y_coordinate density
```

There are about 400*400 points in every text file(as a plane in certain depth).

**Filename**:

```
dep###
```

Here, `###` is a number represents the depth(in Z direction). The number can be an integer or fraction. For example, now I have these files: "dep0", "dep0.5", "dep10", "dep300", that means those data are 400*400 gridded data in x-y plane form for depth of 0, 0.5, 10 and 300.

Now, I would like to pick up the number in the filename (aka the depth) and add it to the third column of each row, combine all of them together. Also the depth should be sorted from minima to maxima. So the output file should looks like this(for example):

```
x_coordinate y_coordinate z_coordinate density
0            0            0            2.5
0            1            0            2.5
...          ...          0            2.6
400          400          0            2.9
0            0            0.5          2.8
...          ...          0.5          2.9
0            0            10           3.2
...          ...          10           3.3
...          ...          300          4.7
...          ...          300          4.8
```

At first I was doing it with this script:

```
for((i=$depmin;i<=$depmax;i++))
do
 if [ -f "xyp/dep"$i ];then
  awk '{print $1, $2,'$i',$3}' "xyp/dep"$i >> "xyzp/area1"
 fi
done
```

Then I figure out it would miss any files which depth is not integer, since the ***variable $i*** in the `for` loop increase by 1 in every round.

I have tried to use `sed` and `find -exec`, but I kept getting errors. The difficulty for me is that I don't quite understand how to use `$`, `''`, `<<<` correctly to redirect or pipe the value to `awk` or other function. Please help me with this problem.

=====================

I have come up with this script:

```
depnumbers=$(ls xyp | sed -e 's/dep//g' |sort -n)
filecount=$(ls xyp | wc -l)

for((i=1;i<=$filecount;i++))
 do
  dep=$(awk '{print $'$i'}' <<< $depnumbers)
  awk '{print $1, $2,'$dep',$3}' "xyp/dep"$dep >> "xyzp/area1"
 done
```

It works just fine. Is there any way to simplify or improve this script for such task? Actually I'm new to bash and still think something is wrong...not sure

Comment: Please edit your post and add an example of a filename with a fraction.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example of the actual data and your desired output. Isn't the order of the rows in the second file important? We can't understand exactly what you need without an example.

Comment: Sorry for the misspell, wrong grammar and unclear statements. Tell me if there are still something not clear.

Comment: What is the name of the file awk is reading ?

Comment: The accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992689/bash-how-to-loop-all-files-in-sorted-order) may help you tidy your loop :-)

Comment: @Jidder The files awk are reading, `"xyp/dep"$i`, means the files are under the folder `xyp`. And the file name is starting with `dep`, following with variable $i which defined in the `for` statement `for((i=$depmin;i<=$depmax;i++))`.

Comment: @Pakox.Wang Look at my answer and let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: @garethTheRed Thanks. I also have this kind of sorting problem in other part of my script...now that's the solution, good to know :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For only adding numbers into the file.

```
awk 'NR>1{print $1,$2,substr(FILENAME,7),$4 }' xyp/dep* > "xyzp/area1"
```

For sorting by numbers.

```
ls -1v xyp/dep* | xargs awk 'NR>1{print $1,$2,substr(FILENAME,7),$4 }' > "xyzp/area1"
```

For sorting from minus numbers.

```
 ls xyp/dep* | sort -t 'p' -k 3 -n | xargs awk 'NR>1{print $1,$2,substr(FILENAME,7),$4 }' > "xyzp/area1"
```

This would regard the character `p` as separator and make the function `sort -n` only affect on the following numbers.

Comment: Because the number that follows the filename doesn't have same digits. If I have files at depth of 1, 3, 10, 15, 20, 300, the reading priority will be like 1=>10=>15=>20=>3=>300, since the `substr` only compares the number from specific position. Also it should be substr(FILENAME,7) because the `FILENAME` contain path `xyp/`. Still many thanks :) I'll have to read some manual.

Comment: @Pakox.Wang Yeah sorry, i didn't test and forgot it included the directory. Will sorting the new file on the third field not work ?

Comment: @Pakox.Wang Check update

Comment: Sorry I just went home...will test tomorrow. Checked the manual and it seems fine... but I want to ask if it's still okay when we have the `depth` number in negative? Just asking, currently have no such issue but I'm aware of it since the data is from Geology model. BTW, I think we should put a wildcard at `ls -1v xyp/dep*`

Comment: Yeah i should have,thanks :) anyway i added another answer for minus/negative numbers

Comment: Not sure if `sort -n` have same problem with the first one _(I think I was wrong in first comment, the reading priority seems to be decided by the shell itself(wildcard) but not the `substr`)_ .But I think that's pretty close to the answer, I'll test it tomorrow. Really appreciate it, I didn't know the usage of `xargs` and `substr` before you answered me, that could be the key.

Comment: I've changed your answer a little bit and it works fine :) Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: @Pakox.Wang No problem and i accepted the change, glad its working :)